# Big data, оптимизация запросов

Tags: sql-server, big-data

Есть следующая простая структура данных

```
Id; fk_Security_Id; DateTime; Price
```

Строка хранит данные по инструменту(активу), дату и время, цену(котировку). Строк в БД на данный момент ~ 1 млрд. 200 млн. (10 инструментов с историей за прошлые 10 лет)

Задача - выборка данных по указанному `fk_Security_Id` и промежутку `DateTime`(например, июль 2000г.) за адекватный промежуток времени (в идеале меньше минуты).

Сначала, я использовал знакомый мне MSSQL и навесил в лоб clustered index на эти 2 поля. В результате поиск по этим 2 полям занимает в районе 35 минут и сожранные 6.5Gb RAM. Не совсем то, что конечно хотелось бы.
Какие варианты решения вижу пока я:

1. Не менять выбранную бд, а изменить саму структуру хранения
   данных. Например разнести в разные таблицы данные по разным инструментам. В
   этом случае конечно будут абсолютно идентичные таблицы с точки
   зрения структуры, но можно будет выиграть некоторое время на поиске и
   дальнейшее добавление новых инструментов не будет влиять на то самое время поиска. И тогда вместо композитного кластерного индекса, индекс
   будет состоять из одного поля - datetime. Также возможно здесь
   имеет смысл вместо поля datetime в качестве индекса брать некий
   timestamp или преобразованный Id. Но не уверен что это даст
   существенный прирост в поиске, хотя стоит попробовать думаю.
2. Использовать какую-нибудь более легковесную бд, например postgres (дружит с необходимым мне EF, что очень хотелось бы) + есть нативная поддержка Sphinx-а например.
3. Использовать какое-нибудь NoSql решение. С данными бд дел не имел, но допускаю,что в моем случае данные укладываются в простую структуру key-value. Правда, наверное те NoSql которые держат данные в RAM мне не подойдут потому что у меня просто столько памяти нету. Хотя, если я не ошибась есть и достаточно шустрые дисковые NoSql , Aerospike например. Но опять же поскольку я с ними не работал я не могу оценить насколько они дадут выигрыш по времени по сравнению с обыными реляционными бд.

База не распределенная, ресурсы машины - 8 потоков и 8Gb RAM. Буду рад любому совету.

Comment: Вы бы план выполнения посмотрели, зачем ему столько RAM - он должен данные сразу на клиента гнать, похоже он их как то еще преобразует (может у вас там группировка или сортировка не точно такая же как ваш ключ индекса)

Comment: У вас выборка подразумевает условия по атрибутам - это никак не key-value. На вашем месте я бы арендовал кластер серверов на ближайшем облаке и распихал бы все в кассандру. Aerospike вам теоретически может подойти, но его бы я пробовал в последнюю очередь. В любом случае задача сводится к распределению нагрузки, и здесь вряд ли можно придумать что-то быстрее кассандры. Есть еще elasticsearch, который гарантированно будет быстро искать, но его довольно долго настраивать, да и не стал бы я его использовать в качестве *хранилища* с поиском.

Comment: Mike, вот спасибо. И впрямь не придал значения, что у меня условие на datetime стоит в виде year(datetime) = x или month(datetime) = y. Вместо это просто поставил сейчас [DateTime] > 'x' AND [DateTime] < 'y'  и всё просто летает на ура.

Comment: Хех, ну с [sargable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sargable) то оно понятно веселее.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пара мыслей (eсли вы всё же остановитесь на MSSQL).

На мой взгляд big-data подразумевает щепетильное отношение к структурам хранения данных и типам хранимых данных.

Сравните, к примеру, размеры различных типов данных для хранения дат и чисел:

```
declare
    @dt datetime = getdate(),
    @dt2 datetime2(0) = getdate(),
    @sdt smalldatetime = getdate(),
    @m money = 1.0,
    @f float = 1.0,
    @dec_15_5 decimal(15,5) = 1.0,
    @r real = 1.0

select
    [datetime] = datalength(@dt),
    [datetime2(0)] = datalength(@dt2),
    [smalldatetime] = datalength(@sdt),
    [money] = datalength(@m),
    [float] = datalength(@f),
    [decimal(15,5)] = datalength(@dec_15_5),
    [real] = datalength(@r)

datetime  datetime2(0)  smalldatetime  money  float  decimal(15,5)  real 
--------- ------------- -------------- ------ ------ -------------- -----
8         6             4              8      8      5              4
```

Если тип столбца DateTime у вас `datetime`, рассмотрите возможность использования, например, типа `smalldatetime` (диапазон значений от 1900-01-01 до 2079-06-06 с точностью 1 минута). Если, тип стоблца Price, к примеру, `float` - рассмотрите возможность использования типов `decimal` (`numeric`) или `real`. Чем меньше размер строки данных, тем больше строк помещается в одну страницу памяти, соответственно легче оперировать ими в запросах. В таблицах с большим числом строк нелишним будет избегать `NULL`-able столбцов (это также сэкономит немного места). Правда следствием компактного хранения может быть некоторое неудобство в написании запросов, когда, например, при вычислении среднего для сохранения точности приходится делать кастинг в тип с большей точностью, а потом обратно. Да и сам кастинг несколько повысит стоимость запроса.

Ваша идея разнести инструменты по таблицам имеет рациональное зерно. Нужно ли их держать в одной таблице, и в самом ли деле нужен Id в таблице, если, к примеру, на неё нет ссылок - решать вам. Однако если разнести данные по таблицам вида

```
create table SomeInstrument
(
    DateTime smalldatetime not NULL primary key,
    Rate real not NULL
)
```

то общий объём хранимых данных явно уменьшится, т.к. не будет столбцов Id и fk_Security_Id.

Если всё же оставите всё в одной таблице, то fk_Security_Id (вместе с primary key таблицы, на которую он ссылается) имеет смысл перевести на тип `tinyint`, раз уж инструментов всего около десятка.